# How to turn off Azure service notifications for a user?

Tags: azure, notifications

From time to time, Azure sends notifications regarding particular service issues or maintenance. Obviously, these notifications are useful for technical specialists but they may be useless and even annoying for management staff. At the same time, a manager (e.g. CEO) may have an administrator role in the Azure cloud. Is there any way to turn off these notifications for a particular user? In the emails, there is a disclaimer that the notifications are mandatory, and there is no link to unsubscribe or to manage email subscriptions.

Comment: If they are administrators the notifications is manadory. No way to opt-out. That comes with the part of being an Administrator. So I suggest you review if they really need to be administrators.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Daniel. May I ask you: have you seen any confirmation about this in the official Microsoft's documentation? I was trying to find it, but, unfortunately, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following information in their Privacy Statement:

> Your communications preferences
>
> You can choose whether you wish to receive promotional communications
> from Microsoft by email, SMS, physical mail, and telephone. If you
> receive promotional email or SMS messages from us and would like to
> opt out, you can do so by following the directions in that message.
> You can also make choices about the receipt of promotional email,
> telephone calls, and postal mail by signing in with your personal
> Microsoft account, and viewing your communication permissions where
> you can update contact information, manage Microsoft-wide contact
> preferences, opt out of email subscriptions, and choose whether to
> share your contact information with Microsoft partners. If you do not
> have a personal Microsoft account, you can manage your Microsoft email
> contact preferences by using this web form. These choices do not apply
> to mandatory service communications that are part of certain Microsoft
> products, programs, activities, or to surveys or other informational
> communications that have their own unsubscribe method.

https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement

So I think that each product you use defines what is mandatory or not, so there is probably not one place to find this since each product is developed by its own team and must be able to send appropriate information about that product.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The case when it is worth to read Privacy Statement.